Visual odometry estimation using viso2_ros
I have been trying to use viso2_ros package for visual odometry with my raspicam. I followed the tutorial here but it seems that it does not work as expected.
I used the following parameters in my launch file
    <!-- Bucketing params -->
    <param name="max_features" value="2" />
    <param name="bucket_width" value="50" />
    <param name="bucket_height" value="50" />

    <!-- Mono params -->
    <param name="camera_height" value="1.0" />
    <param name="camera_pitch" value="0.0" />
    <param name="ransac_iters" value="2000" />
    <param name="inlier_threshold" value="1e-5" />
    <param name="motion_threshold" value="100" />

and what I see is illustrated in the attached image

Any idea why? In the real scenario, the robot is moving forward and then it will go up though a pipe.
Thank you in advance for any help.
